# How to convert image to base64 string in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am developing a windows phone application in which I have to convert image to base64 string and I have to pass that string through Web Service. So I tried many Ways, but I cant able to send it as everytime I am getting error as "Target Invocation error". With this code I can choose the image from library but I cant send through web service.

I used the following code to covert the image:

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    this.imageTribute.Source = image;
    byte[] bytearray = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {

        if (imageTribute.Source == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)imageTribute.Source);

            wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 40, 40, 0, 82);
            bytearray = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    strimage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
}
```

So please if anyone knows about that, help me out. Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

```
void uploadphoto()
{
WebClient webClient1 = new WebClient();
    webClient1.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted);
webClient1.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Web Service"));
}
void webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
var rootobject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject1>(e.Result);
int error = rootobject1.response.errorFlag;
    string message = rootobject1.response.msg;
if (error == 0)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    else
        {
                MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
}
public class Response1
{
public int errorFlag { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public List<string> uploadedImageNames { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject1
{
public Response1 response { get; set; }
}
private void ImageUpload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBoxResult mb = MessageBox.Show("Select the mode of uploading the picture", "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    photoSelection photo = new photoSelection();
    popup.Child = photo;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    photo.camera.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            photoCameraCapture.Show();
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        };
    photo.library.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            photoChooserTask.Show();
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        };
}
```

**EDIT**

[image: StackTrace]

Here I uploaded the stack trace of my error. So please check and reply me.

Answer (score 0):

A Target Invocation Exception error tells you that the application crashed while invoking a method which could be many things.  The real error is in the InnerException.

Look at the InnerException property of the TargetInvocationException object.  This will show you the stack trace and the actual error thrown.

Comment: I have edited my code please see the code and tell me why I am getting the Target Invocation Exception. I am using Webclient to send the image to the web service.

Comment: Please post the stack trace and InnerException

Comment: Actually I am very new to development. Please can you tell how to see the stack trace and InnerException.

Comment: One thing I can see now is that e.Result is throwing an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' error.

Answer (score -1):

Get your file into stream either from resource or from isolatedStorage

```
//getting file from resource
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("image.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
//get Stream Data
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
//initializing bytearray to stream length
byte[] imageData = new byte[streamReader.Length];
//wriing from stream to imagdata
streamReader.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
streamReader.Close();
```

Use isolatedStorageFile to read from isolated storage
now you have your image data in `imageData` and to convert it into base64 use:

```
var baseString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
```

Comment: But I cant able to get the name of image which is selected I think. So how can I give particular name?

Comment: To upload a photo you should use multipart/form-data request. To do that use `HttpWebRequest`. Actually web client do not have `UploadFileAsync` or `DownloadFileAsync` method in `Windows phone 8`.

Comment: Thanx alot. But please can you send me a sample of that how to use HttpWebRequest for my particular code.

Comment: please follow [this code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/30c60f1f-2dbf-4304-86bd-d25759e5c9ce/uploading-multiple-audio-wav-files-using-httpwebrequest-post-multipartformdata). I also use the same and got success.

Comment: It is for audio file. Can you tell me for pictures. And that also sometime I am selecting photo from library and some time I am using camera to take the photo and use that as a photo for upload.

Comment: Mime type application/octet-stream will work for image also... application/octet-stream handles binary files.... so try to implement it. and it will work for image also

Comment: @ShafiqAbbas what ever I've written here is correct and I'm doing the same with my code. This may possible you are using some other framework. this code is for Windows Phone and the `Length` property exist for me. If you cant see such thing, this can not be the correct reason to downvote.